# Words per minute - language list?

Tags: reference-request, spoken-language, speed

I have an idea on how fast a Dutch speaker speaks:

- 130 wpm = medium
- 160 wpm = fast
- 100 wpm = slow

I'd like to have that same knowledge about other languages.

Is there a list somewhere that contains these kind of statistics?

Comment: The question may be well-posed in English (language speed in certain communities/dialects), but cross-languages grouping per word might not give you the good information to compare on since you don't pronounce words, but sounds, and the feeling of speed comes from how fast you pronounce those sounds (or if you pronounce them at all). A more appropriate metric would be syllables per minute, but I don't know where you would get that kind of data (because I never asked myself those questions). I am definitely curious though!

Comment: There was a very interesting report on an experiment at an American university (Vermont?) where they measured the syllables per second of speakers of ten languages. Does anyone have it?

Comment: [Why Some Languages Sound So Fast (*Time*, 8 September 2011)](http://content.time.com/time/health/article/0,8599,2091477,00.html)